# Cosmou and Tartarou - are these Greek Democracy and Golden Horde in Enoch 20.2?

Tags: greek

In Enoch XX.2 (20.2) Uriel is said to be a saint angel over the **kosmoi** and the **tartaroi**. [Codex Panopolitanus Enoch XX.2](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/swete/lxx3/Page_803.html)
By analogy to other facts in 20.3-6 these should be some kind of a collective or society, whether of people or spirits or planets or some other creatures as other angels in 20.3-6 are set upon those.
**Could these be *West* and *East* as in *Hellenic* and *Mongolic* ruled parts of the World?**

One of the meanings of both the kosmoi and the tartaroi is clearly of a hanging piece of distinction or bijouterie.
Yet from the same dictionary article kosmoi has another meaning of a type of society organization in Greece (West) and Tartaria is widely known to be the name of the territory under Golden Horde rule.
It offers to read Horde -> Orda as societal order in the East and Cosmos a societal order of the West.
So this could be read as if Uriel would be set upon both East and West political systems.

At the same time kosmoi and the tartaroi could be the (golden) tokens that the rulers would receive to confirm their status. It is well established that in Horde local vassal rulers had to get a special lable, Russian "ярлык",  Turk "yerligh" or "jaribq", German "Etikett" that could possibly look like an ear-ring or a hanging (golden) piece. If some kind of this labeling custom had also existed in Hellenic (Cosmos) world, it would explain the double parallel meanings of those words.

There are multiple mentions of Cosmos in the both OT and NT but I could not find a definitive explanation of what that is supposed to be. When e.g. Jesus says "I have conquered the Cosmos" in [NT j16:33](https://biblehub.com/john/16-33.htm#lexicon) it is also not exactly clear what he refers to.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Horde

The [greek original](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/swete/lxx3/Page_803.html) does not have any translation neither plain text form. I could not find a nice parallel Greek and English source to quote Book of Enoch.
The English sources translate the XX.2 as follows:

- [Here](http://www.bookofenoch.org/enoch17-23.htm)"20.2 Uriel, one of the Holy Angels; namely the Angel of **thunder and earthquakes**.".
- [And here yet a different version](https://book-ofenoch.com/chapter-20/) "2. Uriel, one of the holy angels, who presides over **clamour and terror**."

Dictionary articles:

- [kosmou kosmima](https://lsj.gr/wiki/%CE%BA%CF%8C%CF%83%CE%BC%CE%BF%CF%82)
- [tartarou tartaroiga](https://lsj.gr/wiki/%CF%84%CE%B1%CF%81%CF%84%CE%B1%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%8D%CE%B3%CE%B1)

Comment: this is the site to quote from all apocrypha, it has couple of English versions like WEB ebible.org/study/

Comment: I tried to find it on ebible.org but failed. Do you mind pointing me to a specific link, please?

Comment: As commonly understood, there are three books of Enoch.  1 Enoch = Ethiopic; 2 Enoch = Slavonic; 3 Enoch = Hebrew.  These are readily available in versions such as those by R H Charles, Joseph Lumpkin,, and James Charlesworth.  I cannot find your referenced text in any of these.

Comment: It is strange that the apocrypha versions don't include this. It should be included in ebible and biblewapp sites.

Comment: I have added the references to the same passage in other sources at the bottom. They seem to be 20th verse in the 2.nd book as the division goes in those sources.

Comment: The extant Greek versions of 1 Enoch are not the original - 1 Enoch was originally composed in either Hebrew or Aramaic, or a mixture of both.  Most are now translated from the Ethiopic Ge'ez language.

Comment: Once the original or other unequivocal sources don't document the original language it seems to me the inner logic of the text or the whole bible corpus takes precedence. But I'd be happy to get a founded answer any way.

Comment: Ah, I guess, I misunderstood your point about the "original", @Dottard.  When I wrote "Greek original" I meant the text in Greek as it is available to me on the Net to differentiate it from any further translation into English or any other language. I do not mean to claim that the original author wrote the book of Enoch in Greek.

How could I say that in proper English in a more straightforward and clear way?

Comment: The source you quote is NOT from the Greek, but by its own admission, "original translation from Ge'ez to English by Prof. Michael A. Knibb, year 1978."  1 Enoch only exists in Greek in a few fragments and thus is almost never used as a translation source.

Comment: Could you please link to that admission? The one I quote first is said to be written in Greek and they date it as between 8th and 9th century. https://ccel.org/ccel/swete/lxx3/lxx3/Page_xvii.html It's in Greek without any translation.

Comment: As I understand the source for Enoch XX.2 in that book is the Codex Panopolitanus found in Greek. I have added this information to my question.